# Why doesn't this (translated) VB.NET code work?

Tags: vb.net, lambda, c#-to-vb.net

I had a piece of C# code converted, but the translated code isn't valid... Can somebody help out?

**C#**

```
<table>
  <% Html.Repeater<Hobby>("Hobbies", "row", "row-alt", (hobby, css) => { %>
  <tr class="<%= css %>">
    <td><%= hobby.Title%></td>
  </tr>
  <% }); %>
</table>
```

**VB**

```
<% Html.Repeater(of Hobby)(Model.Hobbies, "row", "row-alt", Function(hobby, css) Do %>   
  <tr class="<%= css %>">
    <td><%= hobby.Title%></td>
  </tr>      
<%  End Function)%>
```

Comment: The type parameter Jrc3.BLL.Product is not the same as the type Hobby

Comment: Lol, forgot to change... I meant syntactically it's not accepted... "Function(hobby, css) Do" makes VS say that 'Do' is not expected there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting to use a statement lambda in VB.net.  These are not supported in VB.net until Visual Studio 2010.  The previous version of the language only supports expression lambdas which don't work in this scenario

If you are using 2010 you need to remove the `Do` immediately following the `Function` header.  It's not necessary and will instead force the lambda to be an expression lambda instead of a statement lambda.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, but what does this article say then? http://blogs.msdn.com/codeanalysis/archive/2007/09/21/new-for-visual-studio-2008-support-for-anonymous-methods-and-lambda-expressions.aspx